# Python - Random output has a structure

Tags: python, list, random

I am writing a small script for a Tic Tac Toe game in python. I store the Tic Tac Toe grid in a list like this (example of a empty grid): `[[' ', ' ', ' ',], [' ', ' ', ' ',], [' ', ' ', ' ',]]`. These are the following possible string for the list:

- `' '` no player has marked this field
- `'X'` player X
- `'O'` player O

I have written a function that creates an empty grid (`create_grid`), a function that creates a random grid (`create_random_grid`) (this will be used for testing purposes later) and a function that prints the grid in such a manner so that its read-able to the end user (`show_grid`). I am having trouble with the `create_random_grid` function, the other two method work though. Here is how I approached the `create_random_grid` function:

- first create an empty grid using `create_grid`
- iterate over the grid line
- iterate over the character in the line
- change the character to an item randomly selected form here. `['X', 'O', ' ']`
- `return` the grid

**NOTE:** I do not expect that exact output for the *Expected Output*. For the *Actual Output*, I do not always get exactly that but all the lines are always the same.

[image]

I do not know why all the lines are the same. It seems that the last generated line is the one that is used. I added some debug lines in my code along with examples that cleary show my problem. I added line in my code that show me the randomly chosen mark for each slot of the grid, however my output does not correspond to that, except for the last line where they match. I have included other important information as comments in my code. Pastebin link [here](http://pastebin.com/yuGK8bRq)

***CODE:***

```
from random import choice

def create_grid(size=3):
    """
    size: int. The horizontal and vertical height of the grid. By default is set to 3 because thats normal
    returns: lst. A list of lines. lines is a list of strings
        Creates a empty playing field
    """
    x_lst = [' '] * size  # this is a horizontal line of the code
    lst = []  # final list
    for y in range(size):  # we append size times to the lst to get the proper height
        lst.append(x_lst)
    return lst

def show_grid(grid):
    """
    grid: list. A list of lines, where the lines are a list of string
    returns: None
    """
    for line in grid:
        print('[' + ']['.join(line)+']')  # print each symbol in a box

def create_random_grid(size=3):
    """
    size: int. The horizontal and vertical height of the grid. By default is set to 3 because thats normal
    returns: lst. A list of lines. lines is a list of strings
        Creates a grid with random player marks, used for testing purposes
    """
    grid = create_grid()
    symbols = ['X', 'O', ' ']
    for line in range(size):
        for column in range(size):
            # grid[line][column] = choice(symbols)  # what I want to use, but does not work

            # debug, the same version as ^^ but in its smaller steps
            random_item = choice(symbols)
            print 'line: ', line, 'column: ', column, 'symbol chosen: ', random_item  # shows randomly wirrten mark for each slot
            grid[line][column] = random_item  # over-write the indexes of grid with the randomly chosen symbol
    return grid

hardcoded_grid = [['X', ' ', 'X'], [' ', 'O', 'O'], ['O', 'X', ' ']]
grid = create_random_grid()
print('\nThe simple list view of the random grid:\n'), grid
print('\nThis grid was created using the create_random_grid method:\n')
show_grid(grid)
print('\nThis grid was hard coded (to show that the show_grid function works):\n')
show_grid(hardcoded_grid)
```

Comment: It seems strange to use a string with a space in it. An empty string would evaluate to a falsy value making it much easier to check if a space is empty. `if not x_lst[0]` versus `if x_lst[0] == ' '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x_lst = [' '] * size
lst = []
for y in range(size):
    lst.append(x_lst)
```

All elements of `lst` are the same list object. If you want equal but independent lists, create a new list each time:

```
lst = []
for y in range(size):
    lst.append([' '] * size)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your board consists of three references to a single row. You need to make three separate rows, like so:

```
lst = [[' ']*3 for _ in range(3)]
```